# SSRS Maps district by parameter

Tags: ssrs-2008

First time venturing into SSRS maps as I have been tasked with giving a visual representation based on UK districts. So I have my ERSI shape file and have linked the data to an analytical data set to get values by region.

[image]

I want to create a region parameter which means they can select specific region and it shows only that district (at a set zoom level).

From what I have established I need to do this as a sub report. However I cannot find a way to parameterize what area I select in the map itself.

Answer (score 0):

On your main Map report:

1. Left click on the Map to select it
2. In the "Map Layers" section, right click on the Layer that defines your regions and click "Polygon Properties"
3. In the left-hand menu, click "Action" text
4. Click on the "Go to report" radio button

You've then enabled each region/polygon in your geographic data to be selectable/clickable.

7. From "Specify a report", select your sub report
8. Under "Use these parameters to run the report", click "Add" and map your parameters so that your sub report can filter by region.

That's it in a nutshell.

Just an optional extra that might be useful to you. You can enable tooltips on hover-over and text that's visible on each region/polygon in your Map report by:

1. Follow steps 1 and 2 above
2. In the "General" tab, you can define "Label text" that's visible on each region as well as a "tooltip" on hover-over with the mouse cursor